# Cannot Read Property of Undefined error while using Web Sockets with React Native

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

I am new to React Native and Java Script development. I am trying to retrieve a JSON object and display it on client but I am getting "cannot read property of undefined" error. The same works fine when I am using "Fetch" instead of websockets. I am not able to figure out the issue.

I debugged the code and could find out that I do receive the JSON from the server.
Here is my client code:

```
fetchDataWithSockets() 
    {
        var url='ws://localhost:3000/';
        var ws = new WebSocket( url );
        var object;
        ws.onmessage = (e) => {
          object = JSON.parse(e);

        } 
                this.setState({
                    dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(object.movies),
                    isLoading: false,
                    empty: false,
                    documents: object.movies
                });

    }
```

Object on Server:

```
var object = {
  "title": "The Basics - Networking",
  "description": "Your app fetched this from a remote endpoint!",
  "movies": [
    { "title": "Star Wars", "releaseYear": "1977"},
    { "title": "Back to the Future", "releaseYear": "1985"},
    { "title": "The Matrix", "releaseYear": "1999"},
    { "title": "Inception", "releaseYear": "2010"},
    { "title": "Interstellar", "releaseYear": "2014"}
  ]
}
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: See my answer to the similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49030162/8009977

Answer (score 0):

`object` is not completely available in the line `this.setState...`. You have to move your `this.setState` line inside the `onmessage` of the WebSocket. Your code will looks like this:

```
fetchDataWithSockets(){
    var url='ws://localhost:3000/';
    var ws = new WebSocket( url );
    var object;
    ws.onmessage = (e) => {
        object = JSON.parse(e);

        this.setState({
            dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(object.movies),
            isLoading: false,
            empty: false,
            documents: object.movies
        });
    }
}
```